# Haml and Handlebars, how to escape a text between the '<' '>'?

Tags: haml, ember.js, handlebars.js

I need my haml to generate a tag with '{{ }}' inside the < >.
It's not an attribute, I would like it to paste plain text inside the tag.
For example:

```
<a href="..." {{bindAttr class="App.ready:ready"}}>...</a>
```

I searched in the documentation but I could not find how... is this possible with the haml syntax?

Comment: i havent looked much into the gem yet but this might help: https://github.com/jamesotron/hamlbars

Answer (score 3):

I use plain HTML when I need Handlebars inside opening and closing tags.

```
%div
  <div {{action clickAction}}>
  Click Here
  </div>
```

It's ugly, but since HAML has no native way of doing this, it's much better than using another library or complicated hack that somebody invented.

There's not that many of these cases anyway.

Answer (score 0):

`= '<a href="..." {{bindAttr class="App.ready:ready"}}>...</a>'`

If you need string interpolation, you'd have to use double quotes or here-docs and escape appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following to pour out "safe" text:

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper('raw', function (name) {
    return new Handlebars.SafeString(this.get(name) || name);
});
```

...

```
{{raw myProperty}}
```

Comment: Why not just use the built-in triple-bracket syntax?  `{{{myProperty}}}` vs `{{myProperty}}`